# Running pig script gives the error as: job has failed. Stop running all dependent jobs

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need a help in why I am getting an error while running a pig script. But when I try the same script in a smaller data, it executes successfully.

There are a few questions with similar issues, but none of them have the solution.

My script looks like this:

```
A = load ‘test.txt’ using TextLoader();
B = foreach A generate STRSPLIT($0,’”,”’) as t;
C = FILTER B BY (t.$1==2 and t.$2 matches ‘.*xxx.*’);
Store C into temp;
```

The error is:

```
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 40% complete
2013-07-15 14:21:41,914 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201307111759_7495 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2013-07-15 14:21:41,914 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2013-07-15 14:21:42,754 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException: No lease on /xxx/ temp/_temporary/_attempt_201307111759_7495_m_000527_0/part-m-00527 File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_attempt_201307111759_7495_m_000527_0 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:1606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:1597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:1652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFile(FSNamesystem.java:1640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.complete(NameNode.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.c
2013-07-15 14:21:42,754 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It is namenode issue. Could you restart the hadoop cluster and try again ? If you are not the administrator, then delete that file and upload that file again.

Comment: I think the problem might occur when you are processing a very large data and you don't have sufficeint quota. I tried to give as input multiple smaller files instead of a single merged large file. And, this didn't give me the error. I didn't try deleting the file though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that the problem here is LeaseExpiredException. This might be because the output of mapper was removed. One of the reason for this might be due to the quota allocated for the user. In my case, I was running this script in a very large data, and my quota was insufficient to process/store the data.

We can check the quota by the following command:

```
hadoop fs -count -q /user/username
```

Thank you.